# WPF validation not working and Validation.ErrorTemplate is not showing in intellisense

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have a XAML as follows. Not following MVVM for testing purposes. Right now when the textbox focus looses or property changed or whatever neither the exception occurs nor the red color border for the textbox appears. Also  for the textbox when I say `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property is not showing in intellisense and a blue scribbly occurs saying there is a mistake in XAML. How can I make it work?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Applcation5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtdemo" Height="40" Margin="218,140,79,140">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="text" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                        <local:NameVaildation/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="253,0,152,61" RenderTransformOrigin="0.857,5"/>
        <TextBox Height="40" Width="70" Margin="162,239,285,41"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My `MainWindow.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _Text;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public string text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Name is null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally `NameVaildation` class:

```
public class NameVaildation : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string textvalue = value.ToString();

        if (textvalue == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be null");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Validation.ErrorTemplate XAML and how does the TextBox apply this Validation.ErrorTemplate?

Comment: `TextBox.Text` is never `null`, so the binding will never update the value source with `null`; perhaps you want to check `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`?

Comment: My error template is <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        Foreground="DarkOrange" 
        FontSize="12pt">!!!!</TextBlock>

                <Border BorderBrush="DarkRed" BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>....When I say Textbox.Error template I get exception like a first chance of system.markup exception occured in xaml

Comment: Also I have added string.IsNullorEmpty(value)..

Comment: Hint : use `IDataErrorInfo` pattern instead, it is way better than rules. Example : http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Comment: Are you sure that your `NameVaildation` class resides in `Applcation5` namespace? Maybe it is just a typo in XAML.